# How to set a query string value in C# relative urls

Tags: c#, parsing, uri, query-string

Assume there is a relative URL like: `/api/services` or `/api/services?id=4`. What is the best practice to add another query string parameter to the specified URL. For example, adding `type=1` should lead to the following results: `/api/services?type=1` and `/api/services?id=4&type-1`.
The type of the URLs is general, and any part of the standard URI format may exist.

Note that the standard `System.Uri` and `System.UriBuilder` classes have limited capability for relative URIs.

Comment: I solved a similar problem and I didn't find anything simple, so I ended up using the condition myUri.LastIndexOf('?') != -1

Answer (score 0):

Add nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities`.

```cs
namespace so74768078
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test1 = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("/api/services", "type", "1");
            var test2 = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("/api/services?id=4", "type", "1");

            Console.WriteLine(test1);
            Console.WriteLine(test2);
        }
    }
}
```

console output

```
/api/services?type=1
/api/services?id=4&type=1
```